# export CSV file, and downloaded by the browser, using express js

Tags: node.js, csv, express

```
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

exportCSVfile: function(req, res){
    var ws = fs.createWriteStream('my.xls');
    console.log(req.body.save);
    session = req.session;
    if(session.uniqueID){
        if(session.uniqueID.access == 2){
            csv.write([
                ["a1","b1"],
                ["a2","b2"]
            ],{headers:true}).pipe(ws);
        }
    }
}
```

that is my current code, i can get the csv file, but rather than directly write on my disk, i want to make the browser download it. how can i to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but you want to send a csv file through express to the browser so the browser downloads it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First write out a response header setting proper content type and disposition for download.

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + csvFileName
});
```

Then simply pipe the stream created by csv() to response.

```
csv.write([...]).pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attachment()` function to attach your file to response. You can try something like this

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
res.attachment(filename);
stream.pipe(res);
```